# Next.JS Redux dispatch not working in getStaticProps()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

I am pretty new to Next.JS and I was trying to set up Redux with my Next.JS application. Now my page is supposed to display a list of posts that I am calling in from an API. The page renders perfectly when I'm dispatching from `useEffect()` to populate the data on to my page, but `getStaticProps()` or `getServerSideProps()` are not working whatsoever!

Here is a bit of code that will give you a hint of what I've done so far:

**store.js**

```
import { useMemo } from 'react'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer'

const initialState = {}
const middlewares = [thunk]

let store

function initStore(preloadedState = initialState) {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        preloadedState,
        composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
    )
}

export const initializeStore = (preloadedState) => {
    let _store = store ?? initStore(preloadedState)

    if (preloadedState && store) {
        _store = initStore({
            ...store.getState(),
            ...preloadedState,
        })
        store = undefined
    }

    if (typeof window === 'undefined') return _store
    if (!store) store = _store

    return _store
}

export function useStore(initialState) {
    const store = useMemo(() => initializeStore(initialState), [initialState])
    return store
}
```

**action.js**

```
export const fetchPosts = () => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')

    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_POSTS,
        payload: res.data
    })
}
```

**_app.js**

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createWrapper } from 'next-redux-wrapper'
import { useStore } from '../redux/store'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const store = useStore(pageProps.initialReduxState)

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

These are the files that I needed for the basic redux setup. Once my store was set up and I wrapped my app around the `Provider`, I initially though of using `useEffect()` hook to populate data on a component that was rendering inside my `index.js` file.

**component.js**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchPosts } from '../redux/actions/postsAction'

const Posts = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { items } = useSelector(state => state.posts)

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchPosts())
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="">
            <h1>Posts</h1>

            {items.map(post => {
                return (<div key={post.id}>
                    <h3>{post.title}</h3>
                    <p>{post.body}</p>
                </div>)
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Posts
```

This worked perfectly! All my posts were showing up inside the component. The problem occurred when I was trying to achieve the same behaviour with server side rendering (or even SSG). I wanted to populate the data during the pre-render phase but for some reason the items array which is supposed to hold all the data is empty, basically meaning that the disptacher was never called! Here is the piece of code that is bothering me (exactly same as previous code, but this time I'm using `getStaticProps()` instead of `useEffect()`):

**component.js**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchPosts } from '../redux/actions/postsAction'

const Posts = ({ items }) => {
    return (
        <div className="">
            <h1>Posts</h1>

            {items.map(post => {
                return (<div key={post.id}>
                    <h3>{post.title}</h3>
                    <p>{post.body}</p>
                </div>)
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    console.log('Props called')
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { items } = useSelector(state => state.posts)

    dispatch(fetchPosts())
    console.log(items)

    return { props: { items } }
}

export default Posts
```

By running this, I'm getting an error that items is empty! Please help me, I have no clue what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I fixed this issue myself but I forgot to post an answer for it, my bad!

The problem here really is very simple, hooks don't work outside of a functional component!

Answer (score 0):

I think, inside of `getStaticProps` just call API or get datas from DB and returns it as props to `pages/index.js` (any component you want) and inside of this component we can get datas from `getStaticProps` as props.

Also we can set it as global state using `useDispatch` of react-redux. After that any component we can call those states using redux `mapStateToProps`. This is my solution.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a solution if anyone faced this problem,

```
import React from 'react';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {wrapper} from '../store';

export const getStaticProps = wrapper.getStaticProps(store => ({preview}) 
=> {
console.log('2. Page.getStaticProps uses the store to dispatch things');
store.dispatch({
type: 'TICK',
payload: 'was set in other page ' + preview,
 });
});

// you can also use `connect()` instead of hooks
const Page = () => {
const {tick} = useSelector(state => state);
return <div>{tick}</div>;
};


export default Page;
```

Got it from here: https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper